# bash's output redirection - what's the difference between >> and >&, redirecting and duplicating?

Tags: bash, shell-script, io-redirection

I'm trying to understand output redirection, but I'm struggeling. I don't think I really get the differences.

```
1 > file        # -  redirect stdout to file (override mode)
1 >> file       # -  redirect stdout to file (append mode)
2 > 1           # 1) would that also redirect stderr to stdout, replacing stdout?
2 >> 1          # 2) would this redirect stderr to stdout (appending to it,
                #    i.e. haivng both sent to stdout?)
1>&9            # -  duplicates stdout to file descriptor (pointer) 9 
                # 3) what's the difference of 2>&1 to a 2 >> 1? Does >> only run at the end
                #     of output?
echo foo > file # -  redirects output to file (override mode)
>file 2>&1      # -  duplicates stderr to stdout, then redirects to file in override mode 
                # 4) why is this giving me stdout, too, when the syntax is 2>&1, 
                #    i.e. duplicate stderr into stdout - not merge 2 into 1?
```

I'm assuming the ampersand `&` means duplicate, as opposed to redirect. But what's the difference of redirecting `a` to `b` (will `a` remain unchanged?) to duplicating `a` to `b` (will `a` and `b` be the same?)? `2>&1` effectively seems to redirect and merge `2` into `1`, i.e. what would have gone into `2` is now in `1`, but only in `1`... why?

I'm so confused...

Comment: As an also-worthy-of-note aside, if you `set -o noclobber` then it won't *let* you truncate a file that already exists with `>`, but you can still *explicitly* truncate with `>|`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, anything *after* `>` or `>>` is a file name; so `> 1` writes to a file named `1`.

Numbers in the other forms given in your example are file descriptors. By default, programs start with file descriptors 0 (standard input), 1 (standard output) and 2 (standard error) connected; when you start a program from an interactive shell, these are connected to the terminal's input and output (you can see these by running `ls -l /proc/$$/fd` on Linux).

Specifying a number before `>`, `>>` or `>&` specifies the file descriptor you wish to manipulate; the number has to be right in front of the `>` symbol. Thus

```
echo Example 2> stderr
```

will print "Example" and create an empty `stderr` file (which would contain anything sent to the standard error).

You can think of file descriptors as entries in a table, pointing to files; thus by default:

- 0 points to `/dev/tty`
- 1 points to `/dev/tty`
- 2 points to `/dev/tty`

Specifying `1> file` (or simply `> file`) updates file descriptor 1 to point to `file`, opened in truncating mode (so its contents are replaced). Specifying `2> 1` updates file descriptor 2 to point to a file named `1`, opened in truncating mode.

Duplicating file descriptors using `>&` (or `&>`, which is the preferred form) simply updates one file descriptor to point to whatever the other is pointing at. In your last example, `> file` updates file descriptor 1:

- 0 points to `/dev/tty`
- 1 points to `file`
- 2 points to `/dev/tty`

and then `2>&1` updates file descriptor 2:

- 0 points to `/dev/tty`
- 1 points to `file`
- 2 points to `file`

(order is significant: `> file 2>&1` produces the above, `2>&1 > file` would only end up redirecting file descriptor 1).

The `1>&9` form only works if file descriptor 9 has been opened, *e.g.* by copying file descriptor 1 to it (`9>&1`) or by opening a file (`9> file`). This type of construct can be useful to keep track of the original contents of file descriptors when redirecting; thus in a script you could copy 1 and 2 safely away, redirect standard output and error for whatever purpose you need, and then restore them...

The [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Redirections) has all the details.

Comment: Thanks. Incidentally, I had read the manual page before I came here; it's not very n00bie friendly... I take it `/dev/tty` is the [current terminal's process](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8514853/2018047)? I still don't get the order issue, though: `1>file 2&1` redirects `stdout` to `file`, then manipulates `stderr` to be a duplicate of `stdout` - in other words: redirect output to file, do the same for errors (i.e. send error msgs to where std output is going). `2>&1 1>file` says manipulate `stderr` to be a duplicate of `stdout` (so errors now go to std output), then redirect std output to file

Comment: ...How can the result be different? If anything, I'd expect `> file 2>&1` to send `out` to `file`, close `file`, then put `err` to `out`. How come `2>&1 1>file` is putting output to `file`, but error messages to the terminal?

Comment: I think this just helped me with the last bit: "`> p.log 2>&1`
... remember: always read file redirections from left to right. ... First, `stdout` is changed so that it points to our `p.log`. Then, we use the `>&` syntax to duplicate FD 1 and put this duplicate in FD 2. ... `2>&1 > p.log` This will duplicate `stderr` to where `stdout` points (which is the terminal), and then `stdout` will be redirected to p.log. As a result, stdout's messages will be logged, but the error messages will still go to the terminal." http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput#File_Descriptor_Manipulation

Comment: Just to sum up, `2>&1 > file` would be executed left to right. We start with: 0 points to `/dev/tty`, 1 points to `/dev/tty`, 2 points to `/dev/tty`. Then we run `2>&1`, which doesn't change anything. Lastly, we run `1> file`, and the result is: 0 still points to `/dev/tty`, 1 now points to `file`, and 2 still points to `/dev/tty`. Correct? (Bearing in mind that `0` is usually `stdin`, `1` `stdout`, and `2` `stderr`...)

Comment: That's right, in `2>&1 > file`, `2>&1` doesn't change anything. The point I was trying to get across was how to think about all this (descriptors pointing to files), you seem to have understood that ;-).

Comment: Note to self: what you deal with (`input`, `output`, `error output`) and where you send it to (`/dev/tty`, `/dev/null`, `file`) isn't the same. Files and file  descriptors aren't the same. by convention, error output goes on file descriptor `1`, but they aren't the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

You had some wrong assumptions.

---

The general syntax for redirection is:

```
[n]redirection-operator word
```

where `n` is a decimal number denotes a file descriptor. Note that there's no space between `n` and `redirection-operator`.

---

To redirect standard output to file, you need:

```
> file
```

or:

```
1> file
```

`1 > file` means running command `1` and redirect it output to `file`, or explicitly, the same as:

```
1 1> file
```

The same for standard error `2> file` and `>>` operator.

---

To duplicate a file descriptor, you will use:

- `[n]<&word` for input file descriptor
- `[n]>&word` for output file descriptor
- `[n]<>word` to open file descriptor for reading and writing

---

All the above is standard syntax, which will work if you use `#!/bin/sh` for your script.

Some shells have their own extensions, like `bash` with `>&` to redirect both standard out and standard error, `ksh93` with `<>;` for truncating to the offset at command completion.

---

Now, you can see their differences.

The *duplicating* operator only works with file descriptors, while the *redirecting* operator only works with files (which are mapped to file descriptors under the hood).

Comment: Yup, I think my biggest mistake was to assume that `>` and `>&` are related more than they actually are...